# PHP Reload div's content on link click

Tags: php

I'd like to reload a specific div if you click on a link with PHP.

HTML Code:

```
<nav>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    //Reload Content here
    <p>That's a test paragraph for the start page</p>
</div>
```

And now I want to include the page from the href on click into the div.content

How can I catch a link click in php? Is this possible? And how can I include the page into my div.content?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `jQuery`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using Jquery and AJAX if you want to achieve this without a page reload... Otherwise you might want to use a PHP GET request as follows:

```
<nav>
    <a href="?content=register">Register</a>
    <a href="?content=login">Login</a>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['content'])) {

            if (file_exists($_GET['content'] . '.php')) {

                require($_GET['content'] . '.php');
            }
        }
    ?>
    <p>That's a test paragraph for the start page</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed on the server, and cannot reload a `<div>` widhout rendering the whole page. If you absolutly want to use PHP to do this, you need to make an `<iframe>` inside the `<div class=content>` and reload that.

URL parameters is stored in the `$_GET` variable.
For example: foo.com?page=bar can be retrieved with `$_GET['page']`

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['page']; // will return "bar"
?>
```

Example in pure PHP without `<iframe>`

```
<nav>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</nav>
<div class="content">
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['page']))
     {
        // Includes the content. @ is for supressing errors if the file is not found.
        // Can be solved with is_file();
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php
        @include "/path/to/file/".$_GET['page'].".php";
     }  
?>
</div>
```

This is not the most secure way of doing it, because you can manipulate the URL to include other PHP files in your system, but you get the idea.